# Merge two button elements as one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering how to go about making a button that looks like a normal button, but the right side does X and the right side does Y.

For example, when I click the left side of this button it runs one form. I click the right side and it runs another form.
The button needs to look like a normal button, so the user would only see one button.

Comment: Interesting request. :) One idea - invisible css blocks above disabled (normal) button?

Comment: Why not just make 2 buttons look like one, and use JavaScript to style the other one, if you want action on one to change the other?

Comment: @PHPglue - How would you do that?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure how I would add text to the buttons to make it look like one... If anyone could make a JSfiddle that would be much appreciated. Thanks so much for your suggestions, though! :D

Comment: I would suggest SomeKittens solution, but it is possible to handle the click event and based on the position of the mouse in relation to the button, do different things.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sounds like horrible UI.  The user should be able to see the difference between the buttons.  You should create two buttons in a 'pill' formation as such:

[image: split button]

By applying a negative margin to the second button:

```
#second-button {
    margin-left: -4px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cQMvv/)

If you still want to, you can remove the borders to make them merge in to one:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yasinallana/cQMvv/3/)

Answer (score 4):

Something like this would work:

```
<button>
    <span class="left-part">Button</span>
    <span class="right-part">value</span>
</button>
```

Then you can bind different event listeners to the left and right `span`s.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2L8uN/ (and [version](http://jsfiddle.net/2L8uN/1/) with styled span padding's)

Comment: This seems really good. It works perfectly on chrome, although I cannot get it to work on firefox. I'll work on compatibility. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: this is much more sensible

Answer (score 2):

Using jquery, you should do something like :

```
$('#splitbutton').click(function(e) {
    if (e.clientX < $(this).offset().left + $(this).outerWidth() / 2)
        console.log('left');
    else
        console.log('right');
});
```

but i agree, quite unusual UI :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a great idea like this once for the President. One side of the button showered the room with M+Ms, the other started an all-out nuclear war. He said, and I quote, "Great UI man. Always keep 'em guessing!".

(Boom)

Answer (score 0):

A great premade version of what I think you're looking for is the Twitter Bootstrap implementation of "button toolbars". You can check it out [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-toolbar).

Comment: Hello, I was looking for something that looks like one normal button. So it is invisible to the normal user.

Comment: Oh -- then I guess the accepted answer is the best way to do it. I just didn't assume your goal was to prank/confuse your users!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/xuyocica/1 pure css and html javascript free 
[image]